# UICollectionViews not displaying cells when run on iPad

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a UIViewController with three UICollectionViews in it. When I run the app on an iPhone, the app works fine, and the UICollectionViews populate as desired.
For the iPad version I want slightly different behaviour, and so I have to give the cells different sizes relative to the parent than the iPhone version. When I run it though - the two UICollectionViews with dynamically calculated dimensions do not display any cells. I assume the problem must be with with this code:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

if (IDIOM != IPAD)
{
    if (collectionView == self.sourceTanksCollectionView)
    {
        return CGSizeMake(self.sourceTanksCollectionView.frame.size.width, self.sourceTanksCollectionView.frame.size.height * 0.95);
    }
    else if (collectionView == self.destinationTanksCollectionView)
    {
        return CGSizeMake(self.destinationTanksCollectionView.frame.size.width, self.destinationTanksCollectionView.frame.size.height* 0.95);
    }
    else
    {
        return CGSizeMake(50,60);
    }
}
else
{
    CGSize iPadCellSize;
    if (collectionView == self.sourceTanksCollectionView)
    {
        iPadCellSize = CGSizeMake(self.sourceTanksCollectionView.frame.size.width, (self.sourceTanksCollectionView.frame.size.height/self.arrayOfSourceTanks.count));
    }
    else if (collectionView == self.destinationTanksCollectionView)
    {
        iPadCellSize = CGSizeMake(self.destinationTanksCollectionView.frame.size.width, (self.destinationTanksCollectionView.frame.size.height/self.arrayOfDestinationTanks.count));
    }
    else
    {
        iPadCellSize = CGSizeMake(50,60);
    }
    return iPadCellSize;
}
}
```

I have tried making sure the heights and widths of the cells are less than the UICollectionViews in question, but this doesn't make any difference.

OK - I'm still not having any luck with this! The UICollectionViews work on the iPhone5 and iPhone6 I have tested it on - it's just the iPad version. I am hoping this is still something simple. Here is the rest of the code I use for the collectionviews - maybe there is something I have not spotted:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.lhsGradientFillView.firstColor = [UIColor lightBlue];
    self.lhsGradientFillView.secondColor = [UIColor transparentLightBlue];
    self.rhsGradientFillView.firstColor = [UIColor lightBlue];
    self.rhsGradientFillView.secondColor = [UIColor transparentLightBlue];
    self.lhsGradientFillView.gradientDirection = dLeftToRight;
    self.rhsGradientFillView.gradientDirection = dRightToLeft;
    self.currentSelectedMovement = 0;
    self.movementsIndexCollectionView.delegate = self;
    self.movementsIndexCollectionView.dataSource = self;
    self.sourceTanksCollectionView.delegate = self;
    self.sourceTanksCollectionView.dataSource = self;
    self.destinationTanksCollectionView.delegate = self;
    self.destinationTanksCollectionView.dataSource = self;

    self.blendDataProvider = [[BlendDataProvider alloc] init];
    self.blendDataProvider.dataDelegate = self;
    [self.blendDataProvider getArrayOfBlends];

    self.movementIndicatorArrow.direction = dUp;
    self.transferDirectionArrow.direction = dDown;

    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didChangeOrientation:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:[UIDevice currentDevice]];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout* sourceFlowLayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout*)self.sourceTanksCollectionView.collectionViewLayout;
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout* destinationFlowLayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout*)self.destinationTanksCollectionView.collectionViewLayout;

    if (IDIOM==IPAD)
    {
        UICollectionViewFlowLayout* srcLayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout*)self.sourceTanksCollectionView.collectionViewLayout;
        srcLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;
        UICollectionViewFlowLayout* destLayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout*)self.destinationTanksCollectionView.collectionViewLayout;
        destLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;
        sourceFlowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(self.sourceTanksCollectionView.frame.size.width, self.sourceTanksCollectionView.frame.size.height/2);
        destinationFlowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(self.destinationTanksCollectionView.frame.size.width, self.destinationTanksCollectionView.frame.size.height/2);
        [self.sourceTanksCollectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
        [self.destinationTanksCollectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
    }
    else
    {
        UICollectionViewFlowLayout* srcLayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout*)self.sourceTanksCollectionView.collectionViewLayout;
        srcLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
        UICollectionViewFlowLayout* destLayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout*)self.destinationTanksCollectionView.collectionViewLayout;
        destLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
        sourceFlowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(self.sourceTanksCollectionView.frame.size.width, self.sourceTanksCollectionView.frame.size.height/2);
        destinationFlowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(self.destinationTanksCollectionView.frame.size.width, self.destinationTanksCollectionView.frame.size.height/2);
    }
    self.sourceTanksCollectionView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    self.sourceTanksCollectionView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    self.destinationTanksCollectionView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    self.destinationTanksCollectionView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    self.sourceIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    self.destinationIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    self.currentBlend = [self.arrayOfBlends objectAtIndex:0];
    [self.sourceTanksCollectionView setNeedsDisplay];
    [self.destinationTanksCollectionView setNeedsDisplay];


}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{

    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    if (IDIOM!=IPAD)
    {
        if (self.sourceIndexPath.row < self.arrayOfSourceTanks.count)
        {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0 animations: ^{[self.sourceTanksCollectionView reloadData]; }
                             completion:^(BOOL finished){;
                 [self.sourceTanksCollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:self.sourceIndexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:NO];
             }];
            self.sourceTanksCollectionViewPageControl.currentPage = self.sourceIndexPath.row;
        }

        if (self.destinationIndexPath.row < self.arrayOfDestinationTanks.count)
        {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0 animations: ^{[self.destinationTanksCollectionView reloadData];}
                             completion:^(BOOL finished){;
                 [self.destinationTanksCollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:self.destinationIndexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:NO];
             }];
            self.destinationTanksColelctionViewPageControl.currentPage = self.destinationIndexPath.row;
        }
        [self.movementsIndexCollectionView setNeedsDisplay];
    }
    else
    {
        self.sourceTanksCollectionViewPageControl.currentPage = self.sourceIndexPath.row;
        self.destinationTanksColelctionViewPageControl.currentPage = self.destinationIndexPath.row;
        [self.movementsIndexCollectionView setNeedsDisplay];
        [self.sourceTanksCollectionView reloadData];
        [self.destinationTanksCollectionView reloadData];
    }
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([collectionView isEqual:self.movementsIndexCollectionView])
    {
        if ([[self.arrayOfAllMovements objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isKindOfClass:[Movement class]])
        {
            TransfersListCollectionViewCell* tempCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier: @"Transfer List Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

            Movement* thisMovement = [self.arrayOfAllMovements objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

            tempCell.sourceTankLabel.text = thisMovement.sourceTank.tankNumber;
            [tempCell bringSubviewToFront:tempCell.sourceTankLabel];
            tempCell.destinationTankLabel.text = thisMovement.destinationTank.tankNumber;

            tempCell.tankGauge.percentFilled = [thisMovement.transferredVolume doubleValue]/[thisMovement.totalVolume doubleValue];
            tempCell.tankGauge.lightFillColor = [UIColor lightestBlue];
            tempCell.tankGauge.darkFillColor = [UIColor midBlue];

            [tempCell sendSubviewToBack:tempCell.tankGauge];
            [tempCell.tankGauge setNeedsDisplay];
            [tempCell setNeedsDisplay];
            return tempCell;
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

    else if ([collectionView isEqual:self.sourceTanksCollectionView])
    {
        SourceTankCollectionViewCell* tempCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier: @"Source Tank Collection Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        Tank* thisSourceTank = [self.arrayOfSourceTanks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        Product* thisSourceTankProduct = thisSourceTank.tankProduct;
        Movement* thisMovement = [self.currentBlend.movements objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        tempCell.tankNumberLabel.text = thisSourceTank.tankNumber;
        tempCell.tankProductLabel.text = thisSourceTankProduct.name;
        tempCell.tankVolumeLabel.text = thisSourceTank.tankTotalVolume;
        tempCell.percentageFilled = [NSNumber numberWithDouble: [thisSourceTank.tankTotalVolume doubleValue]/[thisSourceTank.tankMaxVolume doubleValue]];
        tempCell.tankVolumeToTransferLabel.text = [thisMovement.totalVolume stringValue];
        tempCell.tankVolumeTransferredLabel.text = [thisMovement.transferredVolume stringValue];
        tempCell.transferStatusLabel.text = thisMovement.status;
        if ([thisMovement.status isEqualToString:@"In Progress"])
        {
            tempCell.transferStatusLabel.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
            tempCell.transferStatusLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
            tempCell.transferStatusLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkBlue];
            tempCell.transferStatusLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightBlue];
        }
        else
        {
            tempCell.transferStatusLabel.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
            tempCell.transferStatusLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 0;
            tempCell.transferStatusLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightBlue];
            tempCell.transferStatusLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkBlue];
        }
        tempCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightBlue];
        tempCell.layer.borderWidth = 1.5;
        tempCell.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor darkBlue] CGColor];
        tempCell.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
        [tempCell setNeedsDisplay];
        return tempCell;
    }

    else if ([collectionView isEqual:self.destinationTanksCollectionView])
    {
        DestinationTankCollectionViewCell* tempCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier: @"Destination Tank Collection Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        Tank* thisDestinationTank = [self.arrayOfDestinationTanks objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
        Product* thisDestinationTankProduct = thisDestinationTank.tankProduct;

        tempCell.tankNumberLabel.text = thisDestinationTank.tankNumber;
        tempCell.tankProductLabel.text = thisDestinationTankProduct.name;
        tempCell.tankVolumeLabel.text = thisDestinationTank.tankTotalVolume;
        tempCell.percentageFilled = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[thisDestinationTank.tankTotalVolume doubleValue]/[thisDestinationTank.tankMaxVolume doubleValue]];

        tempCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightBlue];
        tempCell.layer.borderWidth = 1.5;
        tempCell.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor darkBlue] CGColor];
        tempCell.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
        [tempCell setNeedsDisplay];
        return tempCell;
    }
    return nil;
}
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if (IDIOM != IPAD)
    {
        if (collectionView == self.sourceTanksCollectionView)
        {
            return CGSizeMake(self.sourceTanksCollectionView.frame.size.width, self.sourceTanksCollectionView.frame.size.height * 0.95);
        }
        else if (collectionView == self.destinationTanksCollectionView)
        {
            return CGSizeMake(self.destinationTanksCollectionView.frame.size.width, self.destinationTanksCollectionView.frame.size.height* 0.95);
        }
        else
        {
            return CGSizeMake(50,60);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        CGSize iPadCellSize;
        if (collectionView == self.sourceTanksCollectionView)
        {
            //iPadCellSize = CGSizeMake(self.sourceTanksCollectionView.frame.size.width/4, (self.sourceTanksCollectionView.frame.size.height/self.arrayOfSourceTanks.count)/4);
            iPadCellSize = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
        }
        else if (collectionView == self.destinationTanksCollectionView)
        {
            //iPadCellSize = CGSizeMake(self.destinationTanksCollectionView.frame.size.width/4, (self.destinationTanksCollectionView.frame.size.height/self.arrayOfDestinationTanks.count)/4);
            iPadCellSize = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            iPadCellSize = CGSizeMake(50,60);
        }
        return iPadCellSize;
    }
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    double xInset;
    UIEdgeInsets inset;
    if ([collectionView isEqual:self.movementsIndexCollectionView])
    {
        xInset = (self.movementsIndexCollectionView.frame.size.width/2) - 25;
        inset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, xInset, 0, xInset);

    }
    return inset;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        //we need to make sure that the cell that has been selected has a transfer associated with it!
    if (collectionView == self.movementsIndexCollectionView && [[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath] isKindOfClass:[TransfersListCollectionViewCell class]])
    {

        NSIndexPath* previousCurrentMovement = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:self.currentSelectedMovement inSection:0];
        self.currentSelectedMovement = indexPath.row;
        self.currentMovement = [self.arrayOfAllMovements objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        Movement* thisMovement = [self.arrayOfAllMovements objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        for (Blend* thisBlend in self.arrayOfBlends)
        {
            if (thisBlend.dbId == thisMovement.blendId)
            {
                self.currentBlend = thisBlend;
                [self loadSourceTanksInToArray];
                [self loadDestinationTanksInToArray];

                for (int i=0; i<self.arrayOfSourceTanks.count; i++)
                {
                    Tank* srcTank = [self.arrayOfSourceTanks objectAtIndex:i];
                    if ([thisMovement.sourceTank isEqual:srcTank])
                    {
                        self.sourceIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
                    }
                }

                for (int i=0; i<self.arrayOfDestinationTanks.count; i++)
                {
                    Tank* destTank = [self.arrayOfDestinationTanks objectAtIndex:i];
                    if ([thisMovement.destinationTank isEqual:destTank])
                    {
                        self.destinationIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        [self.movementsIndexCollectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:previousCurrentMovement animated:NO];
        [self.movementsIndexCollectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally];
        [self.movementsIndexCollectionView setNeedsDisplay];
        [self viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the output of `self.arrayOfSourceTanks.count`?

Comment: The arrayOfSourceTanks (and arrayOfDestinationTanks) are both populated as expected (i.e. non-zero)

Comment: When debugging, theiPadCellSize looks like it is the same width as the UICollectionView in question, and the expected height - i.e. 2/3/4... times smaller than the height of the UICollectionView

Comment: I don't know if this is significant or not, but when I check the dimensions of the UICollectionViews in question in viewDidLoad, they are significantly smaller (i.e. much smaller than the cells should be) than later on when it comes to finding out cell size, how many cells etc. But then I calculate the cell size from the frame size of the UICollectionView.